# Umbraco 7: Macros vs Partial Views

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm new to Umbraco, wanted to know when does one use Macros over Partial Views and vice versa.

My understanding is that, both are used to create reusable views on different content pages.

Can someone please help me get an understanding of the same. I'm using Umbraco 7.2.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros are generally reusable elements you want the content editor to use in rich text editors or the grid. 
Partial views are reusable elements you as a developer use in your templates.

Macro's have some other benefits over partial views like built in caching, parameters that can be defined in the backoffice and they can hide exceptions from the end user.

Comment: Thank you Mark. If possible requesting you to please share an example on creating custom Macro that is available on internet.

Comment: Check out this blogpost, it covers the basics: http://www.jondjones.com/learn-umbraco-cms/umbraco-developers-guide/umbraco-core-concepts/what-is-an-umbraco-macro

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark